# JavaScript - Clicking on an image

Tags: javascript, image, object, click

I am programming a browser game in JavaScript and need to create a Card Class.
This class has (with other variables) an image, which should be displayed when I create an object. How do I display the object's image and call a function when the image is clicked?

With this code I can display the image wherever I want, but the OnClick function is called instantly when I open the .htm file instead of when I click in the image.

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">      
  function Card(photo){ // this is my object
      this.randomVariable=42;
      this.pic = new Image(); // creating an Image object inside my Card class.
        this.pic.src=photo;
        this.pic.height = 300;
        this.pic.width = 200;
        this.pic.style.position="absolute";  // this 3 lines should set the image's position, and it does.
        this.pic.style.top = 50 + "px"; 
        this.pic.style.left = 50 + "px";
        this.OnClick = document.write("lala");
  }

  var myObject = new Card("cardback.jpg");
  myObject = document.body.appendChild(coso1.pic); // is this how I should create the image? It appears where I want, but it doesn't seem a "clean" programming.
  myObject.OnClick = document.write("lala" + coso1.pic.offsetLeft + coso1.pic.offsetTop); // this is casted when I open the file, and not when I click on the image. *sadface*

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, some help with detecting when I click on the image and displaying the image in a less dirty way (if it's possible)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CTWWk/1/

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo4w.png';

image.onclick = function(){
      alert('I Clicked an image now !');  
};

var divy = document.getElementById('divy');
divy.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: Why doesn't the image appear when I put your code into an html stuff? <html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo4w.png';

image.onclick = function(){
      alert('I Clicked an image now !');  
};



var divy = document.getElementById('divy');
divy.appendChild(image);


</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I just added some element id="divy" - look at the link I posted - it's the full source [http://jsfiddle.net/CTWWk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/CTWWk/1/)

Comment: It can't be run in plain JavaScript? I may be annoying by this time, but it is important I can understand it well to make much bigger stuff later. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You had to add that divy in the HTML. What is it?

Comment: It's just a container to put the image into - again - look at the link. you can convert it to the document.body: `document.body.appendChild(image);`

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a way to do it in a JavaScript object?

Comment: Do what in js object ? what exactly do you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your code. Hope it helps!

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">    
  function Card(photo){
     var cardInstance = new Image();
     cardInstance.src = photo;
     cardInstance.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          alert(1);
      });
     return cardInstance;
  }  

  var myObject = new Card("cardback.jpg");
  document.body.appendChild(myObject);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the "return cardInstance;" for? How could I do it if I want to have multiple images in my class and show them separately, with a different  eventListener for each of them?